# How to detect Social Network and Redirect to PHP to generate Metatags

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I have a site that is hosted at

example: http://lab.example.com/app

When a social network bot such as facebook/twitter tries too scrape this site, I need it to redirect to a php file which generates the correct meta tags.  I tried to modify the HTACCESS in several ways, but after several research, I can't get the Facebook/Twitter debugger to read it.

**.HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . app/index.html [L]

# allow social media crawlers to work by redirecting them to a server-rendered static version on the page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule album/(\d*)$ http://lab.example.com/app/opengraph.php [P]
```

**OPENGRAPH.PHP**  TEST

```
<?php


makePage();      

function makePage() {
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta property="og:title" content="Title Test" />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Description Test" />
            <meta property="og:image" content="http://68.media.tumblr.com/784fb357523d75590261ba6c5c19e6e7/tumblr_o8punbn6Qo1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg" />
            <!-- etc. -->
        </head>       
    </html>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Hoping someone experienced with HTACCESS can help me out

Comment: Generate those meta tags for every request, safest way. You can't predict which user-agent the existing and future bots will use.

Comment: And Google really, really, **really** frowns on people showing something different to their bot than to regular users.

Comment: You should be including the OG Metatags on __every__ pagwe, regardless of who it is requesting it.

Comment: What do you mean to generate the meta tags for every request? I am trying to avoid using any prerender services at the moment - Since Facebook/Twitter won't read metatags generated by javascript after page load, it's why i'm trying to go this route.  I'll probably remove Google anyways, since Google works better with Single Page Applications.

Comment: The OG Metatags will be on every page on Index.html, it is just I need it to be different when facebook/twitter tries to scrape it.

Answer (score 0):

To provide an answer, not what you asked, but what you are trying to achieve.

"The OG Metatags will be on every page on Index.html, it is just I need it to be different when facebook/twitter tries to scrape it."

Twitter has its own set of og tags ..

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="">
```

As for facebook, all you need to do, is detect the useragent.

```
<?php
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'facebookexternalhit')!==false){
 //Do Facebook Og
}
else{
 // Do basic Og
}
?>
```